# Error ' not supported between instances of float and str ' when I try to use .sort() on a Python list

Tags: python

The error is occurring when I try to sort this data list:

```
    para_planilha = [['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:25', '-', 'ATSV Erlangen', 'FC Eintracht Bamberg', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-02T03:05:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:27', '-', 'Western United', 'Central Coast Mariners', 2.08, 3.75, 3.7, 2.06, 1.78], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:28', '-', 'Kfco Beerschot Wilrijk', 'Club Brugge', 11.0, 1.33, 6.4, 2.5, 1.58], ['2022-04-01T18:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:29', '-', 'CA Fenix', 'Deportivo Merlo', 3.4, 2.32, 3.85, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T23:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:30', '-', 'CA Ituzaingo', 'CA Colegiales', '-', '-', '-', '-', 3.4], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:31', '-', 'Edinburgh City', 'Kelty Hearts', 4.6, 1.72, 5.5, 2.02, '-'], ['2022-04-01T11:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:32', '-', 'Navy FC', 'Khonkaen', 4.3, 2.02, 3.7, 1.85, 1.82], ['2022-04-01T16:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:33', '-', 'Samger FC', 'Banjul United', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:34', '-', 'Connahs Quay', 'Aberystwyth', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:35', '-', 'Caernarfon Town', 'The New Saints', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:36', '-', 'Tuzlaspor', 'Umraniyespor', 4.3, 1.96, 3.85, 1.78, 2.26], ['2022-04-01T17:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:37', '-', 'Yverdon Sport', 'FC Vaduz', 2.22, 3.45, 3.8, 2.06, 1.95], ['2022-04-01T17:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:38', '-', 'Rot-Weiss Essen', 'FC Koln II', '-', '-', '-', 4.3, 1.3], ['2022-04-01T15:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:38', '-', 'Herstedoester IC', 'Avarta', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:39', '-', 'SV Tasmania Berlin', 'Berliner AK', '-', 1.57, 4.8, 2.1, 1.86], ['2022-04-01T16:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:40', '-', 'Tallinna Kalev', 'Paide Linnameeskond', 80.0, '-', '-', 3.35, 1.33], ['2022-04-01T12:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:41', '-', 'Millwall U23', 'Peterborough United U23', 2.18, 2.96, 3.5, 2.56, 1.48], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:42', '-', 'Hull', 'Huddersfield', 2.88, 2.84, 3.35, 1.74, 2.34], ['2022-04-01T23:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:43', '-', 'Palmeiras (W)', 'CR Flamengo (W)', 1.56, 6.0, 4.1, '-', 1.88], ['2022-04-01T16:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:44', '-', 'SFC Opava', 'Vysocina Jihlava', 1.71, 4.6, '-', '-', 1.75], ['2022-04-02T00:10:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:45', '-', 'Belgrano', 'All Boys', '-', '-', 3.75, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T16:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:46', '-', 'FC Zbrojovka Brno', 'Pribram', 1.45, 10.5, 4.3, '-', 1.64], ['2022-04-01T14:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:47', '-', 'FK Nevezis', 'BFA Vilnius', '-', '-', '-', 4.5, '-'], ['2022-04-02T00:15:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:48', '-', 'Resistencia SC', 'Olimpia', '-', 1.84, '-', '-', 1.78], ['2022-04-01T14:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:49', '-', 'FCV Farul Constanta II', 'CS Gloria Albesti', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T14:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:51', '-', 'CSM Deva', 'Vointa Lupac', '-', '-', '-', 2.14, '-'], ['2022-04-01T22:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:52', '-', 'Cerro Porteno', '12 de Octubre de Itaugua', 1.42, '-', '-', '-', 1.7], ['2022-04-01T14:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:53', '-', 'Csm Slatina', 'ACS Vedita Colonesti MS', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T14:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:53', '-', 'CSM Flacara Moreni', 'ACS FC Academica Clinceni 2', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], [2.36, '-'], ['2022-04-01T14:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:55', '-', 'Dinamo Bucuresti II', 'CS Real Bradu', 1.93, '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T14:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:56', '-', 'FCSB II', 'FC Arges II', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:57', '-', 'Mezokovesd-Zsory', 'Gyirmot', 2.16, 4.6, 3.35, 1.78, 2.26], ['2022-04-01T14:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:58', '-', 'CFR Cluj SA II', 'CSM Satu Mare', '-', '-', '-', 2.12, '-'], ['2022-04-02T00:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:59', '-', 'Estudiantes Rio Cuarto', 'Atletico Rafaela', 2.34, '-', 3.0, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-02T00:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:00', '-', 'Gimnasia Jujuy', 'Chaco For Ever', '-', 2.96, 2.8, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:01', '-', 'Fulham U23', 'Birmingham U23', 1.41, '-', '-', 2.8, '-'], ['2022-04-01T19:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:02', '-', 'Girona', 'Malaga', 1.58, 7.4, 4.5, 1.76, '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:04', '-', 'Boca Juniors (W)', 'Gimnasia de La Plata (W)', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T22:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:05', '-', 'Patronato', 'Union Santa Fe', 3.95, 2.28, 3.4, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:06', '-', 'Schaffhausen', 'Neuchatel Xamax', 1.86, 4.6, 3.75, 2.12, '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:07', '-', 'Krka', 'Krsko', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:15:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:08', '-', 'FC Wil', 'Aarau', 3.75, 1.96, 4.5, 2.74, 1.57], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:09', '-', 'BK Hacken (W)', 'Hammarby (W)', 1.41, 8.6, 5.6, 2.48, '-'], ['2022-04-01T15:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:10', '-', 'FK Spartaks', 'Liepajas Metalurgs', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T16:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:11', '-', 'Triglav', 'Drava (Slovenia)', '-', 24.0, '-', 3.2, 1.49], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:12', '-', 'Assyriska BK', 'Varbergs GIF', 2.34, '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-02T01:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:13', '-', 'San Francisco FC', 'Plaza Amador', '-', '-', 2.86, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T14:15:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:14', '-', 'Khaitan', 'Al Yarmouk', 2.16, '-', 3.65, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T10:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:15', '-', 'Maccabi Kabilio Jaffa', 'AS Nordia Jerusalem', '-', 15.0, 6.2, 1.89, 1.93], ['2022-04-01T15:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:16', '-', 'FC Viktoria Otrokovice', 'H Slavia Kromeriz', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T10:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:17', '-', 'Hapoel Azor', 'Ironi Kuseife', 1.9, 3.55, 3.25, 1.78, '-'], ['2022-04-01T14:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:18', '-', 'FC U Craiova 1948', 'CS Mioveni', 2.06, 4.8, 3.2, 1.45, '-'], ['2022-04-01T09:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:19', '-', 'Hapoel Bikat Hayarden', 'Hapoel Bnei Lod', '-', 7.0, 5.1, 1.97, '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:20', '-', 'Toolon Taisto', 'Sexy Poxyt', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:21', '-', 'Chindia Targoviste', 'Dinamo Bucharest', 2.04, 5.3, 3.35, '-', 2.8], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:22', '-', 'PuiU Helsinki', 'HIFK 2', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:15:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:22', '-', 'Sporting Cristal', 'Uni San Martin', '-', 9.8, 6.2, 2.5, 1.57], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:23', '-', 'Siegburger SV\xa004', 'Borussia Freialdenhoven', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T16:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:25', '-', 'Markez Tulkrem', 'Hilal Al Quds', 7.8, 1.55, 4.7, 2.5, 1.5], ['2022-04-01T16:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:25', '-', 'Kolubara Lazarevac', 'Mladost Lucani', '-', '-', '-', 1.89, 1.96], ['2022-04-01T16:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:27', '-', 'Fredericia', 'Hvidovre', 2.26, 3.3, 3.8, '-', 1.84], ['2022-04-01T16:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:27', '-', 'Thisted (W)', 'Fortuna Hjorring (W)', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:29', '-', 'Fremad Amager', 'Jammerbught FC', 1.57, 7.0, 4.5, 2.1, 1.9], ['2022-04-01T13:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:30', '-', 'Maccabi Ahi Nazareth', 'Beitar Tel Aviv Ramla', 2.56, 3.55, 3.1, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-02T00:40:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:31', '-', 'La Equidad', 'Deportivo Cali', '-', 3.8, 2.94, 1.54, '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:31', '-', 'Viborg', 'SonderjyskE', 1.78, 5.5, 3.85, 1.99, 2.0], ['2022-04-01T18:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:32', '-', 'Podbeskidzie B-B', 'LKS Lodz', 2.32, 3.85, 3.3, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:34', '-', 'Sligo Rovers', 'Shelbourne', 1.82, 5.6, 3.7, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:34', '-', 'ASV Drassburg', 'SC Mannsdorf', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T19:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:35', '-', 'Alafoss', 'UMF Tindstoll', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T19:15:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:36', '-', 'IR Reykjavik', 'Throttur', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T16:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:37', '-', 'Gambia Ports Authority', 'Banjul Hawks FC', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:38', '-', 'Red Star', 'Creteil', 1.63, '-', '-', '-', 2.2], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:39', '-', 'FC Bastia-Borgo', 'Stade Briochin', '-', 2.72, 3.05, 1.62, 1.45], ['2022-04-01T15:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:40', '-', 'Moghreb Tetouan', 'Raja Beni Mellal', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:41', '-', 'Orleans', 'Le Mans', 2.42, '-', 3.25, 1.78, 2.28], ['2022-04-01T19:15:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:42', '-', 'Braga', 'Benfica', 3.4, 2.24, 3.6, 2.06, 1.84], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:43', '-', 'Annecy', 'Avranches', 1.58, 7.4, 3.75, 1.71, 2.26], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:44', '-', 'Lierse', 'Waasland-Beveren', 3.2, 2.28, 3.8, '-', 1.75], ['2022-04-01T15:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:45', '-', 'Stade Marocain du Rabat', 'Waf Widad Fes', '-', 5.6, 3.2, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:45', '-', 'Boulogne', 'Sete', 2.46, 3.8, 2.94, 1.56, 2.56], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:46', '-', 'Chambly Oise', 'Chateauroux', 4.3, 2.2, 3.3, 1.63, 2.36], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:47', '-', 'Concarneau', 'Bourg-en-Bresse', '-', '-', 3.1, 1.55, '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:48', '-', 'Villefranche Beaujolais', 'Cholet SO', 1.63, 7.0, '-', 1.92, 2.02], ['2022-04-01T16:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:49', '-', 'Sandecja Nowy Sacz', 'Korona Kielce', '-', '-', 3.05, 1.68, '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:50', '-', 'Alkmaar (W)', 'Feyenoord (W)', '-', '-', '-', 2.9, 1.55], ['2022-04-01T17:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:51', '-', 'ADO Den Haag (W)', 'FC Zwolle (W)', 1.74, '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:52', '-', 'Wexford F.C', 'Cork City', '-', 1.89, '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:53', '-', 'PSV Eindhoven (W)', 'Heerenveen (W)', 1.32, '-', '-', 3.5, '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:54', '-', 'Waterford', 'Longford', 1.59, 5.9, 4.4, '-', 1.9], ['2022-04-01T17:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:55', '-', 'Excelsior (W)', 'Twente (W)', '-', 1.13, '-', '-', 1.17], ['2022-04-02T00:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:56', '-', 'Univ Catolica (Ecu)', 'Barcelona (Ecu)', 2.54, 3.0, 3.3, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-02T02:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:57', '-', 'Emelec', 'LDU', '-', 3.65, '-', 2.34, '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:58', '-', 'St Patricks', 'Drogheda', 1.46, 9.0, 4.8, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:59:59', '-', 'Ayr', 'Hamilton', 2.78, 2.94, 3.25, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T12:15:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:00', '-', 'Shimshon Tel Aviv', 'Maccabi Ashdod B.C.', '-', '-', 3.2, 1.8, '-'], ['2022-04-01T14:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:01', '-', 'Shabab Al Khaleel', 'Shabab Al Dharia', 1.5, '-', '-', 1.99, '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:02', '-', 'SV Meppen', 'Wehen Wiesbaden', 3.9, 2.04, 3.9, 2.08, 1.94], ['2022-04-01T18:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:03', '-', 'Union Berlin', 'FC Koln', 2.44, 3.35, 3.5, 1.92, 2.04], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:04', '-', 'Morton', 'Kilmarnock', 4.4, 2.0, 3.4, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-02T00:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:05', '-', 'Universidad Guadalajara', 'Tampico Madero', 1.9, 5.0, 3.45, 1.77, 2.14], ['2022-04-01T14:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:06', '-', 'CS Constantine', 'Paradou', 1.86, 4.4, '-', '-', 2.62], ['2022-04-01T17:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:07', '-', 'FCM TQS Traiskirchen', 'SC Wiener Neustadt', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:08', '-', 'SC Kalsdorf', 'SC Weiz', 2.12, '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:09', '-', 'Wiener SK', 'Ask-Bsc Bruck/Leitha', 1.64, '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T10:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:10', '-', 'Hapoel Marmorek', 'Bnei Eilat', 1.57, 5.6, '-', 2.06, 1.85], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:11', '-', 'Dundalk', 'UCD', 1.43, 9.0, '-', 2.02, 1.76], ['2022-04-01T19:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:12', '-', 'Finn Harps', 'Shamrock Rovers', 6.0, 1.66, '-', 1.75, 2.34], ['2022-04-01T20:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:13', '-', 'Deportivo Santani', 'Club F de la Mora', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:14', '-', 'Bohemians', 'Derry City', 2.8, 2.88, 3.35, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:15', '-', 'FC Gleisdorf 09', 'RZ Pellets WAC (Am)', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T16:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:16', '-', 'FK Velez Mostar', 'Siroki Brijeg', 2.24, 4.3, '-', 1.72, '-'], ['2022-04-01T14:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:16', '-', 'ASO Chlef', 'US Biskra', 1.8, 7.2, 3.15, '-', 2.86], ['2022-04-01T16:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:17', '-', 'FC Wacker Innsbruck', 'Floridsdorfer Ac', 2.34, 3.25, 3.8, '-', 1.95], ['2022-04-01T16:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:18', '-', 'SK Vorwarts Steyr', 'Austria Wien (A)', 2.48, 2.82, 3.9, '-', 1.88], ['2022-04-01T14:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:19', '-', 'MC Alger', 'Medea', 1.46, '-', '-', 1.72, 2.3], ['2022-04-01T16:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:20', '-', 'FC Juniors OO', 'SV Horn', 2.76, 2.58, 3.55, 2.1, 1.79], ['2022-04-01T17:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:21', '-', 'SV Worgl', 'SV Telfs I', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:25:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:22', '-', 'Grazer AK', 'FC Blau Weiss Linz', '-', 2.1, 3.7, 1.99, '-'], ['2022-04-02T02:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:23', '-', 'San Luis', 'Mazatlan FC', 1.9, 5.3, 3.55, 1.6, 2.42], ['2022-04-01T14:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:24', '-', 'NC Magra', 'NA Hussein Dey', 2.3, '-', 2.72, 1.48, '-'], ['2022-04-01T16:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:25', '-', 'SKU Amstetten', 'SC AUSTRIA LUSTENAU', 3.45, 2.08, 4.1, '-', 1.63], ['2022-04-01T18:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:26', '-', 'Gent (W)', 'Femina WS (W)', '-', '-', '-', 3.9, '-'], ['2022-04-01T16:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:27', '-', 'SV Lafnitz', 'Ksv 1919', 1.53, 9.2, 4.9, '-', 1.76], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:28', '-', 'Kabylie', 'USM Alger', 1.86, 7.4, 3.25, 1.48, 2.62], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:29', '-', 'FC Dordrecht', 'FC Eindhoven', 5.5, 1.72, 4.3, 2.42, 1.69], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:30', '-', 'Helmond Sport', 'MVV Maastricht', 2.06, 3.55, 4.1, 2.5, 1.59], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:31', '-', 'FC Volendam', 'FC Oss', 1.54, 6.8, 4.8, 2.68, 1.52], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:32', '-', 'Roda JC', 'Jong FC Utrecht', 1.31, 13.5, 6.6, 2.94, '-'], ['2022-04-01T14:15:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:33', '-', 'Fk Novi Pazar', 'FK Napredak', 2.68, 2.9, 3.3, 1.92, 2.16], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:34', '-', 'Jong AZ Alkmaar', 'Jong PSV Eindhoven', 3.65, 2.18, 3.9, 2.48, 1.67], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:35', '-', 'Almere City', 'Excelsior', 2.56, 2.72, 4.2, 2.62, 1.57], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:36', '-', 'NAC Breda', 'Jong Ajax Amsterdam', 2.42, 2.78, 4.5, 3.0, 1.44], ['2022-04-01T13:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:38', '-', 'Agudat Sport Ashdod', 'Bnei Yehuda', 2.58, 3.65, 3.0, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:39', '-', 'De Graafschap', 'Emmen', 2.86, 2.8, 3.4, 1.79, 2.14], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:40', '-', 'VVV Venlo', 'ADO Den Haag', 2.9, 2.42, 4.0, 2.32, 1.76], ['2022-04-01T13:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:41', '-', 'Hapoel Akko', 'Hapoel Afula', '-', 3.45, 3.25, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T15:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:43', '-', 'Wolkite Ketema', 'Adama City FC', '-', 2.24, 3.0, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T12:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:44', '-', 'Defence Force SC', 'Arba Minch', '-', '-', 2.86, 1.46, '-'], ['2022-04-01T22:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:44', '-', 'Nacional Potosi', 'Aurora', 1.53, 9.2, 4.7, '-', 1.67], ['2022-04-02T00:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:46', '-', 'Blooming Santa Cruz', 'Always Ready', 2.24, 3.25, 3.75, 2.34, '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:47', '-', 'Galway Utd', 'Cobh Ramblers', 1.61, 8.0, '-', 2.12, 1.75], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:48', '-', 'Athlone Town', 'Bray Wanderers', '-', 1.82, '-', 2.54, 1.64], ['2022-04-01T23:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:49', '-', 'CA Rentistas', 'Penarol', '-', 1.55, '-', 1.95, '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:50', '-', 'Middlesbrough U23', 'Newcastle U23', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:51', '-', 'Nottm Forest U23', 'Wolves U23', 2.2, 3.6, 4.3, 2.66, '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:52', '-', 'Reading U23', 'West Brom U23', '-', 1.91, '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:53', '-', 'Norwich U23', 'Sunderland U23', 1.74, '-', '-', 2.88, '-'], ['2022-04-01T13:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:54', '-', 'Hapoel Umm AL Fahm', 'Sektzia Nes Tziona', '-', 2.56, 3.4, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T13:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:55', '-', 'Hapoel Rishon Lezion', 'Ironi Ramat HaSharon', 2.38, '-', 2.9, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:56', '-', 'Aston Villa U23', 'Stoke U23', '-', 2.46, 3.55, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T14:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:57', '-', 'NK Sesvete', 'Kustosija', 1.89, 4.7, '-', 1.79, '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:15:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:58', '-', 'Swieqi United FC', 'Marsa FC', '-', 1.9, 4.4, 2.2, 1.75], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:00:59', '-', 'Leixoes', 'Penafiel', 2.06, 4.2, 3.4, '-', 2.22], ['2022-04-01T18:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:00', '-', 'Cliftonville', 'Crusaders', 2.32, '-', '-', '-', 1.98], ['2022-04-01T23:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:01', '-', 'OHiggins', 'Coquimbo Unido', 2.16, 4.1, '-', 1.77, '-'], ['2022-04-01T15:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:02', '-', 'San Gwann', 'Pembroke Athleta', '-', 1.75, 3.8, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T20:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:03', '-', 'La Serena', 'Everton De Vina', 3.4, 2.54, 3.2, 1.66, 2.26], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:04', '-', 'SC Telstar', 'Den Bosch', 1.88, '-', '-', '-', 1.68], ['2022-04-01T12:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:05', '-', 'NK Dubrava Zagreb', 'Cibalia Vinkovci', 1.88, 5.2, '-', 1.78, '-'], ['2022-04-01T16:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:06', '-', 'Zamalek', 'G.D. Sagrada Esperanca', '-', '-', '-', 1.94, '-'], ['2022-04-01T19:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:07', '-', 'SS Reyes', 'Racing Santander', 4.2, 2.28, '-', 1.57, '-'], ['2022-04-01T16:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:08', '-', 'FC Kosice', 'Samorin', 1.6, '-', '-', 2.34, '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:09', '-', 'Anderlecht (W)', 'Club Brugge (W)', 1.26, '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T15:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:10', '-', 'Podbrezova', 'FK Puchov', 1.41, 8.6, 5.6, 2.38, 1.6], ['2022-04-01T21:15:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:11', '-', 'Zamora FC', 'Mineros Guayana', 1.99, '-', 3.5, 1.73, '-'], ['2022-04-01T21:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:12', '-', 'CF America (W)', 'FC Juarez (W)', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T23:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:13', '-', 'Deportivo La Guaira', 'Estudiantes de Merida', 2.18, 4.4, 3.25, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T19:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:14', '-', 'CD Castellon', 'Alcoyano', 2.16, '-', 3.15, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T19:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:15', '-', 'Metropolitanos', 'Carabobo FC', 2.3, 4.1, 3.0, 1.68, 2.56], ['2022-04-01T23:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:16', '-', 'Queretaro (W)', 'Club Tijuana (W)', '-', '-', '-', '-', 1.65], ['2022-04-02T02:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:17', '-', 'Deportivo Saprissa', 'Municipal Grecia', 1.63, '-', '-', 1.97, 1.92], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:18', '-', 'Roskilde', 'Vanlose IF', 1.39, 9.0, 6.0, 2.92, 1.53], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:19', '-', 'Hellerup IK', 'Akademisk Boldklub', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T22:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:20', '-', 'Real Cartagena', 'Llaneros FC', 2.26, 3.7, 3.3, 1.72, 2.38], ['2022-04-01T12:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:21', '-', 'NK Orijent U19', 'NK Istra 1961 U19', '-', '-', '-', 2.2, '-'], ['2022-04-01T16:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:22', '-', 'Stal Mielec', 'Cracovia Krakow', 3.65, 2.36, 3.4, 1.68, '-'], ['2022-04-01T13:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:23', '-', 'Etoile Sportive Sahel', 'Jwaneng Galaxy FC', 1.11, 19.0, '-', 2.34, 1.68], ['2022-04-01T13:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:24', '-', 'HNK Sibenik U19', 'NK Varazdin U19', '-', '-', '-', 2.7, '-'], ['2022-04-01T16:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:25', '-', 'Horoya AC', 'AmaZulu', '-', '-', '-', 1.66, '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:26', '-', 'Slask Wroclaw', 'Lech Poznan', 6.2, 1.66, 3.85, 1.79, '-'], ['2022-04-01T16:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:27', '-', 'Riteriai', 'FK Jonava', '-', 36.0, 8.6, 2.4, 1.63], ['2022-04-01T11:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:28', '-', 'Hougang Utd', 'Albirex Niigata (SIN)', 8.2, 1.4, 7.6, 3.35, 1.36], ['2022-04-01T19:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:29', '-', 'Gimnasia La Plata', 'Talleres', 2.68, 3.0, 3.1, '-', 2.26], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:30', '-', 'Babelsberg', 'Union Furstenwalde', 1.44, '-', '-', 2.44, '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:31', '-', 'VfB Homberg', 'Schalke 04 II', 4.9, 1.82, 3.9, 2.02, 1.88], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:32', '-', 'Hertha Berlin II', 'VfB Auerbach', 1.49, '-', '-', 2.66, 1.58], ['2022-04-01T16:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:33', '-', 'FK Babrungas', 'FK Banga II', 1.75, '-', '-', 3.15, 1.47], ['2022-04-01T11:45:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:34', '-', 'Home Utd', 'Balestier Khalsa', 1.18, 23.0, 9.8, 2.2, 1.26], ['2022-04-01T10:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:35', '-', 'Fukuoka', 'Tosu', 2.62, 3.4, 3.0, 1.52, 2.92], ['2022-04-01T17:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:37', '-', 'Havnar Boltfelag II', 'Klaksvikar Itrottarfelag II', '-', 2.02, '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T19:15:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:38', '-', 'Stjarnan (W)', 'Breidablik (W)', '-', 1.92, '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:38', '-', 'Barmbek-Uhlenhorst', 'FC Suderelbe', '-', 1.95, '-', '-', 1.34], ['2022-04-01T22:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:39', '-', 'Central Cordoba (SdE)', 'Huracan', '-', '-', 3.15, 1.62, '-'], ['2022-04-02T00:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:41', '-', 'Banfield', 'Argentinos Juniors', 2.56, '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T16:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:42', '-', 'Ingolstadt', 'Erzgebirge', 2.52, 2.94, 3.6, 2.1, 1.87], ['2022-04-02T00:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:43', '-', 'LD Alajuelense', 'Santos de Guapiles', 1.42, '-', '-', 2.2, '-'], ['2022-04-01T20:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:43', '-', 'CF Union Viera', 'Las Palmas C', 4.3, 2.48, 3.35, 1.78, '-'], ['2022-04-01T20:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:44', '-', 'Ayacucho Futbol Club', 'UTC Cajamarca', 2.08, 3.9, 3.8, 1.99, '-'], ['2022-04-01T03:01:19Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:45', '-', 'Santos Laguna (W)', 'Puebla FC (W)', 2.88, 4.5, 2.26, 1.12, 8.8], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:46', '-', 'CD Pamplona', 'CD Huarte', 2.94, 2.64, 3.6, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T03:01:51Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:47', '-', 'Club Leon FC (W)', 'Cruz Azul (W)', 4.2, 3.15, 2.3, 3.2, 1.42], ['2022-04-01T02:33:13Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:48', '-', 'CS Cartagines', 'ADR Jicaral', 2.1, 11.5, 2.24, 1.07, 17.0], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:49', '-', 'Birmingham (W)', 'Everton (W)', 5.3, 1.7, 3.95, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:50', '-', 'Illertissen', 'Unterhaching', 2.56, 2.84, 3.45, '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T21:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:51', '-', 'AD Guanacasteca', 'Guadalupe F.C', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:52', '-', 'SC Eltersdorf', 'TSV Rain/Lech', 2.32, 3.25, 4.0, 2.7, '-'], ['2022-04-01T17:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:53', '-', 'FC Memmingen', 'Viktoria Aschaffenburg', 2.84, 2.6, '-', 2.24, '-'], ['2022-04-01T18:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:54', '-', 'CD Gares', 'UDC Txantrea', '-', 1.46, '-', 2.42, '-'], ['2022-04-01T15:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:55', '-', 'Zilina', 'Ruzomberok', 2.48, 3.3, 3.75, 2.08, 1.83], ['2022-04-01T16:30:00Z', '2022/04/01 01:01:56', '-', 'Dynamo Dresden', 'Schalke 04', 4.9, 1.86, 3.85, 2.06, 1.82]]

    para_planilha.sort()
```

I've seen some people indicating something like:

```
para_planilha = para_planilha.astype('str')
para_planilha.sort()
```

But this error appears:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

How should I proceed to solve this problem and get sort this list?

Comment: You input is a 2D list.  How do you want to sort it, or what is the expected output?

Comment: Hello @TimBiegeleisen , I wish to sort this list according to the first value of each line in the list

Comment: `.astype` is a numpy operation.  Did you intend to turn this into a numpy array?

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts No no, actually I just need to sort the list and return it to its original pattern: ```[[''],[''],['']]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your list data.  I replaced the string "]," with the string "],\n" so I could see the structure.  The 30th entry is wrong:

```
...
['2022-04-01T14:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:53', '-', 'Csm Slatina', 'ACS Vedita Colonesti MS', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
['2022-04-01T14:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:53', '-', 'CSM Flacara Moreni', 'ACS FC Academica Clinceni 2', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
[2.36, '-'],
['2022-04-01T14:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:55', '-', 'Dinamo Bucuresti II', 'CS Real Bradu', 1.93, '-', '-', '-', '-'],
['2022-04-01T14:00:00Z', '2022/04/01 00:58:56', '-', 'FCSB II', 'FC Arges II', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
...
```

If you fix the data, it will sort just fine.

#### Followup

You can fix the data via

```
para_planiha = [k for k in para_planiha if len(k) > 2]
```

Comment: That's the problem, there's no way I can remove this line from the answer I get, so my question about there being some way to sort even though there's this problem in between. In this case, is there any way to get around this problem and accept, for example, filter only lines that contain 10 values?

Comment: Of course there is.  `para_planiha = [k for k in para_planiha if len(k) > 2]`.

Comment: @BrondbyIF `sorted(filter(lambda x: len(x)==10, para_planilha), key=lambda x: x[0])`

Comment: Thank you both very much, this filtering model perfectly solved my need, if you can add this option in the answers it would be interesting, if you want me to edit the question to better fit the answer, I edit without problems!

Comment: @mozway -- the sorted `lambda` is unnecessary.  It will sort that way by default.

Comment: @Tim actually, it is unnecessary to sort based on the rest. Also in case of mixed type in the other fields this prevents failure

Comment: @BrondbyIF sure, I added as answer

Answer (score 3):

In base Python, we can try sorting using a lambda expression:

```py
para_planilha.sort(key=lambda row: row[0])
```

But note that you have some 1D lists in there whose first element is *not* a datetime string, such as `[2.36, '-']`, which appears first in the sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to ensure having only lists of the expected size:

```
new_list = sorted(filter(lambda x: len(x)==10, para_planilha), key=lambda x: x[0])
```

*NB. As discussed in the comments, the key is optional in `sorted` but doing so ensures, 1-maintaining original order in case of ties, 2- not having errors in case the other fields contain mixed types*